# Image border-HTML

Tags: html, css, image, border

PS: I don't want to use CSS.
I put borders for my image and now I can't make it appear at the center of the page. No matter what I do it stays on the left side.This is my code:

```
<div align="center" style="padding:5px;border:thin solid black;width:500px;">
        <p align="center">``
  Les fraise des bois sont souvent de petite taille.<br>
  <i>source:<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Fraise_des_boisFL16.jpg" 
   target="_blank"><u>Wikimedia</u></a>, licence CC BY-SA</i>
          </p>
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Fraise_des_boisFL16.jpg" 
         alt="pic pour Fragaria Vesca" width="400px" height="350px">
            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnvhk.png)

Comment: Where is your CSS (inline CSS is still CSS)? There is no reason why `div` should be centered, try to find how to do it.

Comment: PS: don't re-add useless tag. Read the description of the tag before using them. The *web* tag is clearly labeled width *DO NOT USE*

Comment: Hi, you are already using CSS in the style=.... so don't worry about using a bit more. The question linked to has masses of useful information in it about centering but you don't need to have a separate <style> section in your document if you don't want to (though it is normally the standard way of doing things). You can put the suggested styling for centering in a style=... inline, in the way you already are using such an attribute.